# How remote instances work on Coldfusion Clustering?

Tags: load-balancing, cluster, coldfusion

I have just decided to set up my site using ColdFusion clustering in the staging environment. 
I need to find out what code adjustments are required when we move to a cluster environment. 
I have two machines where Coldfusion server is installed.
Till now Steps I followed:

1. On CFServer_1 I have created a instance.(cfinstance_1)
2. On CFServer_2 I have created another instance. (cfinstance_2)
3. On CFServer_1 I have created a Cluster using these two instances.
4. Now on CFServer_1 I have created a IIS site(testsite.com) pointing to my codebase.
5. Now On CFServer_1, Using the Web Configuration Tool I have associated testsite.com with the cluster.

Now my question is Do I  also need to set up the code base on the second server(CFServer_2), Create a site in IIS with same name(testsite.com) and associate the site with the cfinstance_2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Refer to this question of Adobe forum.

https://forums.adobe.com/message/6515641#6515641